# PHP & mySQL : Date + Time Storage

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I've been reading about storing and displaying dates and times in mySQL, but I don't seem to find an answer that suits my needs or I'm incapable of coding my own one. I guess being full of doubts doesn't help at all.

The thing is, I have a mySQL table with a field (text) which I would like to contain certain times and dates. At the moment I'm working with "d/m/Y H:i" format, but I'm pretty sure that's not neat. I'm using that format because it's the format I want it to be displayed on the site.

Could anyone tell me what the correct way of handling this issue would be? Maybe I have to store the date and time in another format and convert it when it's going to be be displayed on the site.

Comment: MySql has a `DATETIME` column type. Why are you using text?

Comment: The correct way would be to use a datetime field. You can then sort by dates.

Comment: `d/m/Y H:i` is a DISPLAY format. you store in native mysql formats at all times (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`), and FORMAT that date value into your human-readable version at display time. Storing in the native formats opens all of mysql's date/time functions, native sorting/grouping, etc... Storing as text/varchar gives... text.

Comment: Use the standard `datetime` field type -> `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` then use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert/insert AND [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert/display

Comment: Thank you guys, gonna practice a bit converting between date formats so at least I'm a bit confident on what I'm doing hehe Maybe it's a n00b question but can't I give you guys points or something like that for answering? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should store them as TIMESTAMP or DATETIME (check the differences [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html))

and then convert them when you write or read the values, for example:

```
INSERT INTO table (date_time) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

SELECT date_format(date_time, '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') as date_time FROM table ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i would say your guess would be the best way to do it. Store it in seconds since EPOCH and then convert using any multitude of ways that php offers:

take a look at this:

[epoch time stamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

the epoch time stamp is valid for ANY time zone. Which makes your server location not important. You could show time for any time zone as long as your parse it correctly with php (or you could even do it client-side with JS)

Comment: Someone said before that there's a proper field type for storing this kind of data, and that it gives proper functions for sorting, grouping,etc ... I think I'm gonna try to do it the way it's supposed to be done hehe Thanks for your help though, appreciate it!

Comment: @Dan, downside to using epoch is pre-epoch(1970) dates -> `Jan 1, 1950`

Comment: @sean yes that is the downside, agreed